# Echo woocommerce product thumbnail?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im trying to echo WooCommerce thumbail of producs onto an orderform.

Not sure how though though. This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php echo  woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail();?>
```

This give me the WooCommerce thumbnail placeholder. **How do I pull the right one for each item in my orderform?** The orderform has fields for order id, creationdate, status and price, so it does pull the proper id´s somewhere.

This is examples of the meta keys and other fields that pull info for each order on the same form, if any of this makes any sense.

```
 <a href="<?php echo $order->get_view_order_url(); ?>">
  <?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>
  foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
      $order      = wc_get_order();
      $order->populate( $customer_order );
      $item_count = $order->get_item_count();
      $customer_orders = get_posts( 
                             apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 
                                 array(
                                     'numberposts' => $order_count,
                                     'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
                                     'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
                                     'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types('view-orders'),
                                     'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses())
                                 ) 
                             ) 
                         );
```

This is how the php is set up. I added the first table class for the immage.

```
  <tr>              

        <th class="order-number"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Image', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>

            <th class="order-number"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>

            <th class="order-date"><span class="nobr"><?php _e( 'Date', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></th>

  </tr>
```

Then Im trying to add the image.

```
<td class="order-image”>

<?php  echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail(); ?>

</td>



<td class="order-number">

<a href="<?php echo $order->get_view_order_url(); ?>">

<?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?>

</a>

</td>



<td class="order-date”>

<time datetime="<?php echo date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?>"><?php echo date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) ); ?></time>

                </td>
```

Comment: An order doesn't have a thumbnail. The items in the order do.

Comment: Your right. I´ll edit my question.

Comment: Also, you spelled woocommerce wrong in your echo.

Comment: What are you trying to change from WooCommerce's default order form?

Comment: I have an orderform for uses where they can se their previous orders. They can se each order with fields for ordernumber, date of purchase, total costs and so on, but no thumbnail of the product, which im trying to set. @helgatheviking

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that WooCommerce already has all the items/costs/thumbnails for previous orders in the My Accounts section and customers can "order again" directly from their My Account area.

But, assuming you have the order ID you can get to the product thumbnails with the following. This will output a small list of items with their thumbnails and product name:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
$items = $order->get_items();
if( $items ) {
    echo '<ul class="ordered-items">';
    foreach( $items as $item ){
        $id = isset( $item['variation_id'] ) ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'];
        $product = wc_get_product( $id );
        echo '<li>'. $product->get_image() . $product->get_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

**Edit: To integrate into your code** I would probably do the following

```
function so_28179558_get_order_thumbnail( $order ){

    if( is_numeric( $order ) ){
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    }

    if( is_wp_error( $order ) ){
        return;
    }

    $order_thumb = '';

    $items = $order->get_items();
    if( $items ) {
        foreach( $items as $item ){
            $id = isset( $item['variation_id'] ) ? $item['variation_id'] : $item['product_id'];
            $product = wc_get_product( $id );
            $order_thumb = $product->get_image();
            continue;
        }
    }

    return $order_thumb;
}
```

Then you can use it in your template like so:

```
<td class="order-image”>

<?php echo so_28179558_get_order_thumbnail( $order ); ?>

</td>
```

Comment: Well i do have the list already, i just want to ad images to it. heres a screenshot of my list: http://i.stack.imgur.com/e24ac.png. As you can see, i already added the imagefield, and at the moment its echoing the woocommerce placeholder. @helgatheviking

Comment: Your screenshot appears to be showing a list of orders. As I mentioned earlier orders do not have thumbnails. If you want to get a thumbnail for the first product in an order (for example) to use there, you could apply my code and just break out of the `foreach()` after the first thumbnail is found.

Comment: Hmm. I did try to manipulate the code you gave, but i didnt get it to work. Do you think you could give me an example? Thank you! @helgatheviking

Comment: This *is* the example. You will need to post more of your code if you want me to try to blend the two together.

Comment: Ok gotcha . Updated the post @helgatheviking